# Forward slash in aspx parameter causes error

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, jquery-mobile

In the href below, when the ItemID parameter, which is a string, contains a "/" forward slash, it causes the current page, ViewQuickQuote.aspx, to reload instead of going to the SelectedItem.aspx page.  I know everything else is working fine because this only happens when there is an ItemID with a forward slash in the ID.

```
  <li><a href="SelectedItem.aspx?itemID=<%=ItemID %>">View Inventory and Pricing</a></li>
```

**Example**

```
<a href="SelectedItem.aspx?itemID=HON.TH6320WF1005/U" class="ui-link-inherit">View Inventory and Pricing</a>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like when the `ItemID` has a "/" in it? (Best to load in a browser & hit 'view source')

Comment: <a href="SelectedItem.aspx?itemID=HON.TH6320WF1005/U" class="ui-link-inherit">View Inventory and Pricing</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to UrlEncode the ItemID:

```
<a href="SelectedItem.aspx?itemID=<%=HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ItemID) %>">View Inventory and Pricing</a>
```

This is located in the `System.Web` namespace.

And to un-encode use the method `HttpUtility.UrlDecode()`

Comment: no luck, but it's probably because I'm doing something wrong. I added the HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(ItemID) in the aspx file, but it just errors out.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was my bad. I typed before I thought :). Try the new code and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: that didn't work either.  I also tried using HttpUntility.UrlEncode in the C# code behind for the aspx page, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Found and fixed the problem.  I was just putting it in the wrong place.  Using HttpUtility.UrlEncode() definitely fixed my issue.  If you will post a new answer I will approve it. This is what I needed:
<a href="SelectedItem.aspx?itemID=<%=HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ItemID) %>">View Inventory and Pricing</a>

Comment: Glad to hear! Let me know what it was and I'll update my answer.